# Is there a way to set Spring's @ResponseStatus `reason` field from inside its class?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to return the below custom exception in Spring, and don't want to hardcode the reason since it should be used for any incorrect values, yet also state the reason it's throwing the error.

Custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException
{
    public BadRequestException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I'm throwing the exception from a switch statement's default.  I could add `reason="Invalid details option: errorToBeInsertedHere` to `@ResponseStatus`, but would rather be able to set the error based on the specific error during runtime.
Currently, I'm running a JUnit test on it, and am failing with the error:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I need to have it set the Error message, which is the `reason` field in the `@ResponseStatus`, to my custom exception, but have been yet to be successful.  How can I do so within `BadRequestException`?

Comment: Try to inherit from `ResponseStatusException` instead  `RuntimeException`.